# Titanium native UI on desktop

Tags: user-interface, desktop-application, native, titanium

I would lie to build a desktop app with Titanium and i thought that the API would give me access to a native ui for desktop. But reading the documentation it seems like the native ui api is directed only to mobile development, while for desktop you have to build the UI yourself in html and js and it will not be native code (with the risk of low performance animation and graphic).

Am i right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. Titanium Desktop only WebKit UI is possible: HTML5+js and/or PHP/Ruby/Python. You can see Tweetanium on git to see how Desktop/Mobile application can be designed. But simply also in mobile you can use a webkit view... It'sn't fast as native UI on mobile but it makes your UI code reusable in both world.
This is exactly what happens on PhoneGap project.